# How to store my password and login for my remote repository?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Sourcetree or terminal on MacBook to manage my repositories on **three** servers. But for everyone of them there is different username and password.

Why Sourcetree/terminal never asks for the first of them, and always asks for the second? Additionally, for the third one, there is an issue:

[image]

Server admin said that this is because more than 5 unauthorized tries to login without success... but I didn't login to that repository, although, as admin says this was from my IP address. Why?

1. What can I do to prevent from unauthorized logging?
2. How to force Git to remember my username and password, and not to ask every time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can save your password login and for HTTPS connections with SourceTree, but **you should not do that**, as it will be very unsecure.

If you can, use SSH protocol for authentication with a key instead of password. You can add the same key for may servers.
Learn more about [this method here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) for example.

Comment: it is too complicated:) any simple suggestions?

Comment: It's GIT 101, @BartłomiejSemańczyk. You only have to set it up once, and there are many step-by-step guides.

Comment: So, connecting to 3 servers also isn't, but you're doing it :)

Comment: ok, one question. Where a lot of unathorized connections comes from? SourceTree does it?

Comment: According to screenshot, you trying to connect over SSH on port 22. My guess is that your service provider doesn't accept password over SSH. Good for them.

Comment: ok, you are right, will you help me to set up protocol for authentication with a key from site you suggested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136215/discussion-between-tymek-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).